# What does an undefined symbol runtime error mean when calling a constructor for Mitsuba add-on?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, rendering

I am trying to implement a custom add-on for mitsuba, but when I use the Heightfield I have defined in another function call(WaveBrdfAccel) in main.cpp it compiles without any problems but when I try to render the scene I get an error that says: undefined symbol: _ZTVN7mitsuba11HeightfieldE

What am I doing wrong in the call of this constructor?

I am trying this on Mitsuba version 0.5.0 (Linux, 64 bit).
If I remove the heightfield parameter from the WaveBrdfAccel declaration then This error does not occur which leads me to believe​ there is something wrong in the way I am calling it but I cannot figure it out.

Here is my main.cpp file :

```cpp
GPTWorkResultTest *spec;
                spec->SpectrumInit(); 

            GPTWorkResultEXR heightfieldImage(heightfieldFilename);
            Heightfield heightfield(&heightfieldImage, texelWidth, vertScale);
            Query query;
                query.mu_p = Vector2(mu_x, mu_y);
                query.sigma_p = sigma_p;
                query.lambda = lambda;

            WaveBrdfAccel waveBrdfAccel(&heightfield, diffModel);
```

the Heightfield and WaveBrdfAccel class both in waveBrdf.h:

```cpp
class Heightfield {
public:
     explicit Heightfield() {}
     Heightfield(GPTWorkResultEXR *heightfieldImage, Float texelWidth = 1.0, Float vertScale = 1.0)
        : mHeightfieldImage(heightfieldImage), mTexelWidth(texelWidth), mVertScale(vertScale) {}
    GaborKernel g(int i, int j, Float F, Float lambda);

    Vector2 n(Float i, Float j);
public:
    GPTWorkResultEXR *mHeightfieldImage;
    Float mTexelWidth;      // in microns.
    Float mVertScale;
    MTS_DECLARE_CLASS()

};

class WaveBrdfAccel {
public:

explicit WaveBrdfAccel(Heightfield *heightfield, string method);

 comp queryIntegral(const Query &query, int layer, int xIndex, int yIndex);


MTS_DECLARE_CLASS()
```

and finally the inclusion in waveBrdf.cpp:

```cpp
WaveBrdfAccel::WaveBrdfAccel(Heightfield *heightfield, string method) {
cout << "IT IS ACTUALLY running wave" << endl;
}


MTS_IMPLEMENT_CLASS(WaveBrdfAccel, false, WorkResult)
```

**EDIT:**

*I am not sure exactly why this is the case but I managed to fix it by simply separating the class definitions into sperate header files. If anyone knows why this worked would love to know!*

Comment: The missing symbol is the vtable for `mitsuba::Heightfield`—is that your type?

Comment: Yes, that was the type I am trying to use but for some reason when I try to use that type in another function call it compiles but throws errors when I actually try to render the scene.

Comment: If that type is polymorphic, it’s because of `MTS_DECLARE_CLASS`—and that might declare a [key method](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html) that you need to define.

Comment: Unfortunately, that creates more problems. `no ‘const mitsuba::Class* mitsuba::WaveBrdfAccel::getClass() const’ member function declared in class ‘mitsuba::WaveBrdfAccel’'''`

Comment: I wasn’t saying to remove that macro, but to understand it and add a method definition if required.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! I am not sure exactly why this is the case but I managed to fix it by simply separating the class definitions into sperate header files.